# How to add comma separator to integer value in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django model table, I have a field for salaries. I how do i add comma separator to my entries. e.g 100000 --> 100,000

My model table looks like this

```
class employeeDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee_name")
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Department_Choices)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Title_Choices)
    salary = models.IntegerField(max_length=10) <--- FIELD
    date_employed = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

Comment: You don't do that in the models. Models are used to *store* information in the database. This is done in templates/views/forms. These focus on how to present and validate data.

Comment: also, you can make use of [`intcomma` filter (django humanize)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) to do so

Comment: In particular, I'd look at the `intcomma` template filter from the `humanize` module for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to handle this is a Decimal Field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield

Answer (score 0):

**For Django Templates you can use this :**

```
{{ value|floatformat:2|intcomma }}
```

**For Fields** :

```
included_ids =  models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` is not appropriate for this - a) it's been deprecated since version 1.9 and b) even when it was around it stored the data as a `CharField` in the database, which is not what you want for a a numeric type.

Comment: If CommaSeparatedIntegerField is no longer appropriate, how does one accept integers with comma separated thousands and store them as numbers in the database?

Comment: @Mustafamond77 you need to specify the `localize` argument to `True`. See [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms) Given that you have the `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` settings etc. set properly Django will properly handle sanitizing the input.